# LDAP Queries are very slow on SSL (Java - SpringFramework)

Tags: spring, ssl, ldap

We have a web application in Java (Spring Framework). For authentication and user management, we are using SSO with LDAP.

The LDAP context is as defined in the bean below:

```
<bean id="legacyLdapContext" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
   <property name="url" value="ldaps://aaa.bbb.ccc.edu:636"/>
    <property name="base" value="cn=Users,dc=bbb,dc=ccc,dc=edu"/>
    <property name="userDn" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="*****"/>
    <property name="pooled" value="true"/>
    <property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">
        <map>
            <entry>
                <key>
                    <value>java.naming.security.authentication</value>
                </key>
                <value>simple</value>
            </entry>
            <entry key="java.naming.referral">
                <value>ignore</value>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Everything works fine, but the connection/queries are very slow.
If the same configuration is changed to non ssl (`ldap://aaa.bbb.ccc.edu:389') it is lightening fast. A query that takes the non SSL context just a few seconds, takes the SSL context 7 minutes.

Is there any LDAPS related configuration missing? I have installed the certificate to JVM using the steps here http://javacolors.blogspot.in/2012/05/how-to-register-ssl-certificates-in.html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force the JVM to pool SSL connections, add the following line to your Apache Tomcat /bin/setenv.sh ({{setenv.bat}} for Windows) file

On Linux:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.protocol='plain ssl' -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.authentication='none simple DIGEST-MD5'"
```

On Windows:

```
JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.protocol="plain ssl" -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.authentication="none simple DIGEST-MD5"
```

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWDKB/Performance+problem+when+using+LDAPS